# Can't access web server when the server's connected to vpn

Tags: vpn, web-server, apache2

First things first, I'm new to this and don't fully know what I'm doing.

I have apache2 running on my ras-pi. My router is port forwarded appropriately. When I start the machine and connect to its external IP all works well, and I receive the website content. 
When I connect the server to a VPN service (expressvpn), and I try to connect to the new external IP address, I meet a page that just says
`403 Forbidden | nginx`

I'm not running nginx, so it seems that my requests are going to another server entirely??

Can someone explain the difference between how requests are handled to a web server that is connected/not to a VPN? Or drop a useful resource to check out?

Comment: It's a web server, why are you connecting it to a VPN?

Comment: It doubles as a torrenting staion :/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you do not have Nginx installed? If they are both using the same port, that is not good. You can find out with Apt.

```
apt list --installed nginx
```

While you can probably more easily remove Nginx,

```
apt remove nginx
```

...Apache and Nginx can be configured to work together.

[How to Configure Nginx and Apache Together on the same Ubuntu VPS or Dedicated Server](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-configure-nginx-and-apache-together-in-ubuntu/)

That still might mean fixing the same error, however.

[How to Fix 403 Forbidden Error in NGINX Ubuntu](https://www.websitevidya.com/fix-403-forbidden-error-nginx-ubuntu/#:%7E:text=4%20Ways%20Fix%20403%20Forbidden%20Error%201%20Wrong,by%20IP.%20...%204%20No%20index%20files.%20)

What works on Ubuntu should work on RaspiOS.

One more possibility...?

Your commercial VPN server is an Nginx server. The problem you may be having is perhaps you are using a shared or dedicated IP with your VPN service without creating a static IP for your web server.

[How to Set Static IP Address and Configure Network in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/set-add-static-ip-address-in-linux/)

Another helpful link on how to set a static IP.

[Set a static IP address on Ubuntu 18 or newer](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/set-a-static-ip-address-on-an-ubuntu-18-or-newer-system/)

Answer (score 0):

When you connect your ras-pi server which has apache2 on it over vpn, the external ip address becomes vpn providers server address. If that provider does not forward any port to your NAT'ed ip address, no one can reach to your server.

It is like this :

```
client wants https://vpnip:Yourserverport --> VPN Service Provider --> ??? To which ip should I send this ???

client wants https://modemswanip:serverport --> your modem -(port forwarding to LAN IP)--> ras-pi (apache2)
```